# How can I install an Ecobee with no C-wire and no panel in the air handler?

Tags: wiring, thermostat-c-wire

I am looking to install an Ecobee but I have reached a C wire issue. Ecobee support didn't think it would be possible without adding another wire but they didn't have the schematic. I am just wondering if anyone could confirm it's not possible without running another wire or not.

[image: Inside of Air Handler]

[image: Schematic]

Comment: How many conductors are there in the cable between your thermostat and the air handler?

Comment: Can you get us a close-up shot of the junction where the thermostat wires connect to the air handler's internal wiring? (it's on the far right)

Answer (score 1):

There is a 24 Volt transformer in your Air handler. The 24 volt output is Red and Brown.

If you do not have those at Ecobee, run a new cable.